# Check element CSS display with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

Is it possible to check if an element's CSS `display == block` or `none` using JavaScript?

Answer (score 179, accepted):

As sdleihssirhc says below, if the element's `display` is being inherited or being specified by a CSS rule, you'll need to [get its computed style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle):

```
return window.getComputedStyle(element, null).display;
```

Elements have a `style` property that will tell you what you want, if the style was declared inline or with JavaScript:

```
console.log(document.getElementById('someIDThatExists').style.display);
```

will give you a string value.

Comment: What if it has not inline css?

Comment: For simplicity, why not just always get the computed style?

Comment: what is `currentStyle`? never heard of it, also checked `document.body.currentStyle` and got nothing (wasn't surprised)

Comment: @vsync (and for future reference) [According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/currentStyle), it's a proprietary property of old version of Internet Explorer.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  Answer updated for the modern web.

Comment: its giving a null string in my case

Comment: Also this is MDN Reference for the [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) method

Answer (score 90):

If the style was declared inline or with JavaScript, you can just get at the `style` object:

```
return element.style.display === 'block';
```

Otherwise, you'll have to get the computed style, and there are browser inconsistencies. IE uses a simple `currentStyle` object, but everyone else uses a method:

```
return element.currentStyle ? element.currentStyle.display :
                              getComputedStyle(element, null).display;
```

The `null` was required in Firefox version 3 and below.

Comment: should this not be == in this case?

Comment: @Kai The triple equal doesn't do type coercion. [Crockford explains why](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html), in the section called "`===` and `!==` Operators."

Comment: That's pretty interesting. Funny how something like this can just escape notice after so many years of programming. I always adopted the suggestion that === was strict boolean. Good to know.

Comment: @Kai: There's no problem with using `===` rather than `==` here, but equally there's no advantage either. Both operands are guaranteed to be strings, so both operators perform exactly the same steps.

Comment: It looks like getComputedStyle is supported from IE 9 onwards - http://caniuse.com/getcomputedstyle

Comment: Five and a half years after this answer was posted, are there still browser inconsistencies we need to worry about?

Comment: @hippietrail And almost 10 years later (2019-10-27) there are still problems. Check [what MDN reports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

Answer (score 44):

For jQuery, do you mean like this?

```
$('#object').css('display');
```

You can check it like this:

```
if($('#object').css('display') === 'block')
{
    //do something
}
else
{
    //something else
}
```

Comment: Avoid over-complicating the answer. I know that jQuery is becoming somewhat of a standard, but there's no reason to add an entire framework just to check an element's display style.

Comment: Yeah but I did this because everyone else gave the raw javascript answer, so if he was using jquery but did not specify then there would be some use in the post

Comment: *I know that jQuery is becoming somewhat of a standard*
What a thing to read!

Answer (score 22):

This answer is not exactly what you want, but it might be useful in some cases. If you know the element has some dimensions when displayed, you can also use this:

```
var hasDisplayNone = (element.offsetHeight === 0 && element.offsetWidth === 0);
```

EDIT: Why this might be better than direct check of CSS `display` property? Because you do not need to check all parent elements. If some parent element has `display: none`, its children are hidden too but still has `element.style.display !== 'none'`.

Comment: Indeed, this is useful.

Answer (score 8):

yes.

```
var displayValue = document.getElementById('yourid').style.display;
```

Answer (score 5):

Basic JavaScript:

```
if (document.getElementById("elementId").style.display == 'block') { 
  alert('this Element is block'); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To find out if it's visible with plain JavaScript, check whether the display property is 'none' (don't check for 'block', it could also be blank or 'inline' and still be visible):

```
var isVisible = (elt.style.display != "none");
```

If you are using jQuery, you can use this instead:

```
var isVisible = $elt.is(":visible");
```

Answer (score 2):

I just found the function `element.checkVisibility()` which is returning `false` when `display: none` is set.

Honestly, I cannot find any documentation for it, so I do not know if it is Chrome specific.

Comment: Seems to be supported by [everything but Safari](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_element_checkvisibility), which is about typical.

Answer (score 1):

You can check it with for example jQuery:

```
$("#elementID").css('display');
```

It will return string with information about display property of this element.

Answer (score 0):

With pure javascript you can check the `style.display` property. With jQuery you can use `$('#id').css('display')`