# Javascript change display CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im completely new to Javascript, this is what i want:
Guy clicks on an element, so i trigger an `onclick` and i want to run a JS function, all clear so i need a JS function, what this function needs to do:

- Check if the display of element `#mobilemenu` is block or none.
- When it is block change it to none, when its none change it to block.

What i found so far was this:

```
function Change(){
document.getElementById("mobilemenu").style.display = "block"; }
```

But i am stuck on checking if it is currently block or none. I am kinda new to JS so maybe it is super easy (as i think) but i can't find a proper tutorial or some examples.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of  [stackoverflow question][1]




  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866229/can-you-check-an-objects-css-display-with-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Just add an `if-else`.

```
function Change(){
    var displayVal = document.getElementById("mobilemenu").style.display;

    if (displayVal == "block")
        document.getElementById("mobilemenu").style.display = "none";
    else if (displayVal == "none")
        document.getElementById("mobilemenu").style.display = "block";
}
```

Here is a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vaa9goLe/

Comment: Thanks man works properly, actually the same as im used to in PHP, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `if`/`else` statement to check whether the element is displayed, and then show or hide it accordingly:

```
function Change() {
    /* Put the mobilemenu into a variable */
    var mobilemenu = document.getElementById("mobilemenu");

    /* Check the display property of the element's style object */
    if (mobilemenu.style.display !== "block") {
        /* The element isn't display: block; so show it */
        mobilemenu.style.display = "block"; 
    } else {
        /* The element is display: block; so hide it */
        mobilemenu.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man works properly, actually the same as im used to in PHP, thanks!

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV At the start #mobilemenu is defined as display: none; but else it indeed wont work.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use `getComputedStyle` in case your element doesn't have initial `display` value to ensure your function will always work.

```
var element = document.getElementById('btn');

element.onclick = function() { 
    var mydiv = document.getElementById('mydiv'),
        isVisible = (mydiv.currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(mydiv, '')).display == 'block'; 
    if (isVisible){
        mydiv.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        mydiv.style.display = 'block';
    }
};
```

jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ykypcmt2/

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```
<div id="mobilemenu" style="display:block"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function Change(){
var contentId = document.getElementById("mobilemenu");
contentId.style.display == "block" ? contentId.style.display = "none" : 
contentId.style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

Comment: @Chiel shortest way :)

Comment: where is the checking -if the display of element #mobilemenu is block or none ?

Comment: @Md.ArafatAlMahmud i have used ternary operator contentId.style.display == "block" ? contentId.style.display = "none" : 
contentId.style.display = "block"; this statement check whether style is block or not

Comment: @Md.ArafatAlMahmud or copy my code and run in your local you can understand :)

Comment: @Md.ArafatAlMahmud look deep there is a condition inside that ,it is a conditional operator syntax like  test ? expression1 : expression2

Comment: inline, inherit etc. are also display properties

Answer (score 0):

If the div had style value anything other than `block` or `none` , the following code should do nothing and preserve the original style value.

```
function Change(){

        document.getElementById("mobilemenu").style.display = ( document.getElementById("mobilemenu").style.display === "block" ) ? "none" :  ( document.getElementById("mobilemenu").style.display === "none" ) ? "block" : document.getElementById("mobilemenu").style.display ;
}
```