# Javascript if function with showing and hiding elements: In depth analysis of why if works in some cases and not others

Tags: javascript, html, css

The purpose of the code is to hide/show an element when the header element is clicked. Why code works and doesn't isn't clear.

**Example 1**

```
function showHideAnswers (id) {
    var x = document.getElementById(id);
    if (x.style.display === "") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } 
}
```

The above code works. Notice the display if comparision of "" rather than none.

**Example 2**

```
function showHideAnswers(id) {
   var x = document.getElementById(id);
   if (x.style.display === "none") {                                                            
       x.style.display = 'block';
   } 
}
```

This code does not work. Notice display being compared to "none", which I think is the part that is causing it to fail; however, "none" works in example 3.

**Example 3**

```
function showHideAnswers(id) {
    var x = document.getElementById(id);
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
       x.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
       x.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

This code works, which causes me to be confused as to why example 2 doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you check an object's CSS display with JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866229/can-you-check-an-objects-css-display-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`element.style` will return the value only inline style is present otherwise "" will be returned

Use [**`Window.getComputedStyle`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) instead!

```js
function showHideAnswers(id) {
  var x = document.getElementById(id);
  var style = window.getComputedStyle(x, null);
  if (style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    x.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='elem'>Element</div>
<button onclick="showHideAnswers('elem')">Click me!</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

in the second example you are asking if x.style.display is equal to the string "none". [the default value of display is inline](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) so its checking if "inline" === "none". To fix the problem you must put the x.style.display to "none" before you run this code

Answer (score 1):

In example 1, it will not work if `display` is already set to anything. (This will only show if display is unset, no hiding).

In example 2, you will only get action if `display` is explicitly set to `none` already. (This will only show if the element isn't already hidden, no hiding)

In example 3 you have an `else` clause which covers the opposite case, and so it will work for both cases (show and hide). Another reason that 3 works is because if `display` is unset, then the `else` clause will cause it to be set to `none`, and then `block` and vice-versa as you continue to call the `function`.