# How to know parent / container style using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I get idea from :

[Can you check an object's CSS display with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866229/can-you-check-an-objects-css-display-with-javascript)

Now look to my code below :

**HTML :**

```
<div style="display: none">
 <input type="text" id="myInput" value="5">
</div>
```

**Javascript :**

```
console.log(document.getElementById('myInput').value);
console.log(document.getElementById('myInput').style.display);
```

**Result in my computer** is show nothing on my browser console.

> **My problem :**
>
> I need to know the parent of input type text style. cause if the
>   parent style is none make the input type text show nothing when i try to get
>   value of input type text. So the main question is how to get parent style **WITHOUT add
>   new id/class/name in div**?

Comment: `.parentNode`? (Possibly recursively.) Or `.parent()`, with jQuery. You may want [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) rather than `.style`, too.

Comment: Can i get example with your solution for my case ? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.parentNode` attribute with `style` in order to get the specific CSS properties you're looking for. All of them are listed on the object. The HTML would be:

```
  <div style="display: none">
    <div id='one'>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and the javascript would be:

```
var node = document.getElementById('one');

console.log(node.parentNode.style.display);
```

[See the fiddle](http://jsbin.com/pawavoheko/edit?html,js,console)

Comment: Is it able to handle if multi level child ?

Comment: Yes. You just keep chaining the `parentNode` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**parentElement**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement) to get the parent of the `input` & [**getComputedStyle**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) to get the style of the parent element

```
var parentElem = document.getElementById('myInput').parentElement;
//getComputedStyle will give all the properties
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(parentElem, null).display)
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/6jxpsdb6/1/)

Comment: Is it able to handle if multi level child ?

Answer (score 0):

Use .parent() with jQuery here is implemented

```js
$('[type=text]').parent().css({'display':'block', 'background' : 'red','padding':'10px'});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="display: none">
 <input type="text" id="myInput" value="5">
</div>
```